# C# Newtonsoft.Json кастомная десириализация

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть JSON следующей структуры:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            {
                "id": 1615765077617,
                "type": "feed",
                "attributes": {
                    "from": { ... },
                    "message": "Ignat добавил проект <a href=\"https://freelancehunt.com/project/opublikovat-prilozhenie-appstore-sozdano/855530.html\">Опубликовать приложение в AppStore - Создано в Unity</a>",
                    "is_new": false,
                    "created_at": "2021-03-15T01:37:58+02:00"
            },
            "links": { ... }
        }
        ... // такие же по структуре элементы
    ],
    ... // остальной контент
}
```

И такой класс:

```
public class FhFeed
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно, мне нужны только данные из `attributes`. Я хочу, что бы я мог просто написать:

```
var feed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FhFeed[]>(jsonString);
```

Я видел, что этого можно добится сделав свой конвертер [(вот тут про это)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm). Но я не увидел там каких-либо нетривиальных примеров, и не могу разобратся, как пропустить ненужную инфу до определённого токена, например.

Comment: Вы можете создать структуру классов, но ненужные поля просто в нее не добавлять. То есть делаете точно так же как если бы выполняли полную десереализацию, но без ненужных свойств в классах.

Comment: @aepot тоесть, вы предлагаете создать класс оболочку, допустим, FhResponse и в нём List<FhFeed> Data. Ок, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Я любитель потоковой обработки данных: если можно что-то обработать по частям, не загружая целиком в память, не потребляя лишних ресурсов, то так и следует делать.

К моему личному сожалению, потоковая обработка таких форматов, как xml/json и прочих мало распространена. Поэтому хочу показать пример.

```
var feeds = new List<FhFeed>();
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var textReader = new StreamReader("test.json"))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    while (jsonReader.Read())
    {
        if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName &&
            (string)jsonReader.Value == "attributes")
        {
            _ = jsonReader.Read();                        
            var feed = serializer.Deserialize<FhFeed>(jsonReader);
            feeds.Add(feed);
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно, тут есть нюанс: мы опираемся на свойство "attributes". Если в json есть свойства с таким же именем в других местах, то этот код окажется нерабочим. Тогда придётся вводить дополнительные проверки.
Тут могут сказать, что поэтому и боятся использовать `JsonReader`. Но если писать конвертер, то там придётся делать те же самые проверки.

Comment: А не проще ли через `Utf8JsonReader`? Да и по ресурсам экономнее выйдет.

Comment: @aepot - Скорее всего да, будет лучше. Но у автора в вопросе Newtonsoft, поэтому код с этой либой.